# Polymode changes from ESS-mode to Markdown-mode whenever I press enter

Tags: ess, r, markdown, polymode

When I am editing .Rmd file within a polymode chunk, the mode switches from ESS to Markdown mode whenever I press enter.  However, it switches back to ess-mode whenver I save the file.

I will try to demonstrate this:
<kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>major-mode</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
major-mode is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.
Its value is ‘ess-r-mode’
Original value was fundamental-mode
Local in buffer hw5.Rmd[R]; global value is fundamental-mode
```

```
x <- runif(100)
```

I run this command with no problem but then I hit enter

````
```{r}
x <- runif(100)


```
````

<kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>major-mode</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
major-mode is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.
Its value is ‘markdown-mode’
Original value was fundamental-mode
Local in buffer hw5.Rmd; global value is fundamental-mode
```

Obviously, I have now lost the ess functionality until I save the file.

<kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd>

Now it is back to ess-mode.
<kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>major-mode</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
major-mode is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.
Its value is ‘ess-r-mode’
Original value was fundamental-mode
Local in buffer hw5.Rmd[R]; global value is fundamental-mode
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason I was having this problem is that I didn't have `(require 'poly-R)` in my init file.  I only had `(require 'poly-markdown)`. After adding `(require 'poly-R)`, I can now press <kbd>Enter</kbd> within a chunk and it will stay in ess-r-mode.